# tensorboard: profile option not showing

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to setup tensorboard to show profile information so I can debug a slow model.

I have following the steps on https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler

Running `pip freeze | grep tensorboard` shows:

```
tensorboard==2.8.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-profile==2.8.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
```

Running `/sbin/ldconfig -N -v $(sed 's/:/ /g' <<< $LD_LIBRARY_PATH) | grep libcupti` shows:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/local/cuda-11.6/targets/x86_64-linux/lib' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/x86_64-linux/lib' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
        libcupti.so.11.6 -> libcupti.so.2022.1.1
        libcupti.so.11.4 -> libcupti.so.2021.2.0
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libcuda.so.1 is not a symbolic link

        libcupti.so.10.1 -> libcupti.so.10.1.208
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring
```

The instruction page was not clear what output should be shown, but I assumed the references to libcupti.so indicates success.

Tensorboard was started with `tensorboard --logdir logs/`, which outputs:

```
2022-04-08 17:42:03.872466: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:922] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-04-08 17:42:03.947825: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:922] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-04-08 17:42:03.948334: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:922] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.

NOTE: Using experimental fast data loading logic. To disable, pass
    "--load_fast=false" and report issues on GitHub. More details:
    https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/4784

Serving TensorBoard on localhost; to expose to the network, use a proxy or pass --bind_all
```

However the tensorboard GUI does not display a profile tab:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing the code to add the tensorboard callback:

```
    tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
        log_dir=os.path.join(self.run_folder.value, 'logs'),
        histogram_freq=1,
        profile_batch='100,120'
```

Answer (score 0):

By default tensorboard profiling is disabled, you have to set profile_batch='1, batch_size' for it to work. You can set for size smaller than batch size if you dont want to profile for all the batches.